# Generated class from freezed creates duplicate FromJson method

Tags: flutter, hive, freezed, json-serializable

I have a class which I am trying to use with Freezed, Json Serializable, and Hive. After running `dart run build_runner build` and generating the necessary classes, my compiler gives me the following error:

`: Error: Can't use '_$FooBarFromJson' because it is declared more than once.`

and

`: Error: '_$FooBarFromJson' is already declared in this scope.`

```
part 'foobar.freezed.dart';
part 'foobar.g.dart';

@freezed
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class FooBar extends HiveObject with _$FooBar  {

  factory FooBar({
    @HiveField(0) required int baz
  }) = _FooBar;

  factory FooBar.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$FooBarFromJson(json);
  }
}
```

After looking through the generated classes, my `foobar.g.dart` file contains the following methods:

```
FooBar _$FooBarFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => FooBar(
      baz: json['baz'] as int,
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$FooBarToJson(FooBar instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'baz': instance.baz,
    };

_$_FooBar _$$_FooBarFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    _$_FooBar(
      baz: json['baz'] as int,
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$$_FooBarToJson(_$_FooBar instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'baz': instance.baz,
    };
```

And my `foobar.freezed.dart` contains this method:

```
FooBar _$FooBarFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return _FooBar.fromJson(json);
}
```

I've noticed that other files that get converted only have the methods with the `_$$_` prefix in `foobar.g.dart`, whereas `_$FooBarFromJson` is being created in both `foobar.freezed.dart` and `foobar.g.dart`, which is the cause of the errors. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the following [this comment in a freezed issue](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed/issues/232#issuecomment-658730167) and as shown in the package readme example, you need to place the `@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)` inside the class in the following manner:

```dart
part 'foobar.freezed.dart';
part 'foobar.g.dart';

@freezed
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class FooBar extends HiveObject with _$FooBar  {
  @JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true) // <~~~ here

  factory FooBar({
    @HiveField(0) required int baz
  }) = _FooBar;


  factory FooBar.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$FooBarFromJson(json);
  }
}
```

You will notice this will give you the following warning:

```
The annotation 'JsonSerializable' can only be used on classes
```

This is a known issue/limitation and the maintainer recommends disabling that specific warning as discussed [here](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed/issues/488).

I believe an alternative approach is to create `build.yaml` and specify `explicitToJson` in there but I don't have much knowledge there.

Comment: Thank you!! I was about to bang my head against the wall!!